# How to import 3dmax model in cocos3d Example iphone

Tags: iphone, cocos3d

I am working with cocos3d Game development I have to import 3dmax model in my application can anyone suggest how to work with cocos3d??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation, cocos3d ships with a loader framework which adds a category on the class CC3World with a method for loading PowerVR POD-files called

```
addContentFromPODResourceFile:
```

Further, the vendor of PowerVR makes available a [plugin for 3dsmax](http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/powervr-pvrgeopod.asp) enabling POD-file exporting of 3ds scenes.

I have not tried it myself, so YMMV.